# Сериализация Xml: пустая строка

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, xml, сериализация, теги

Имеется следующий код:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static XmlSerializerNamespaces emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("") });

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"D:\Temp\1.xml";
            People test = new People { Name = "Sarah", Address = "" };
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
            using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
                ser.Serialize(stream, test, emptyNamespaces);
        }
    }

    public class People
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

После выполнения получаю xml следующего содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<People>
  <Name>Sarah</Name>
  <Address />
</People>
```

Требуется чтобы при пустой строке xml содержал также открывающий и закрывающий теги:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<People>
  <Name>Sarah</Name>
  <Address></Address>
</People>
```

Как сделать это?

---

Набросал такое регулярное выражение для замены, вроде работает корректно (есть специалисты по регекспам?):

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"<(\w+)\s*/>", @"<$1></$1>");
```

Возможно ли на его основе состряпать адаптер для потока?
Как это сделать?

Comment: А почему требуется? Это валидный XML.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, xml вполне валиден и соответствует спецификации. Но суть в том, что такие xml используются в системе электронного документооборота со сторонней организацией и ПО на их стороне (по неизвестным мне причинам) не обрабатывает наши файлы в первом случае, но корректно работает во втором. Увы, повлиять на это очень проблематично.

Comment: Понятно, совместимость с чужим багом :-( Приходится делать и такое, да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать через кастомный `XmlTextWriter`, который будет принудительно писать полный закрывающий элемент:

```
public class MyXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public MyXmlTextWriter(Stream stream) : base(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"D:\Temp\1.xml";
    People test = new People { Name = "Sarah", Address = "" };
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
    using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
    {
        using (var writer = new MyXmlTextWriter(stream))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer , test, emptyNamespaces);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>взято с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539555/prevent-self-closing-tags-in-xmlserializer-when-no-data-is-present</sub>

Comment: Но в одну строку (для ПО это конечно же не проблема)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan `writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;` скорее всего поможет (не проверял)

Comment: да, это фиксит проблему.

Comment: Только закрывающий тег оказывается на другой строчке